# Second pushforward

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $F$ be a smooth function between two smooth manifolds $M$ and $N$, then pushforward of $F$ at $x \in M$ is a map from tangent space of $F$ at $x$ and tangent space of $N$ at $F(x)$. So the pushforward at $v \in T_xM$ of the pushforward is a map from tangent space of $T_xM$ at v to tangent space of $T_{F(x)}N$ at DF(v). From calculus I know that the second total derivative at a point eats two vectors. Is it true then that elements of tangent space to the tangent space are pairs of vectors? If not then why and what is tangent space of tangent space to a manifold? Concrete examples im R^n would be nice.

Comment: The tangent space to a tangent space isn't a really well-defined concept, you instead need the tangent bundle. Specifically, given $f: M \to N$ we get an induced pushforward $Df: TM \to TN$ with its own induced pushforward $D^2f: TTM \to TTN$. A generic tangent space will then be $T_{(p, v)}(TM)$, and so if we fix the base point $p \in M$ and suppress it we get a differential $D^2f: T_v(TM) \to T_{Df(v)}(TN)$. This differential eats a single vector $w \in T_v(TM)$ and varies $w$ along $v$. We can also view it as taking two vectors: simply let $v$ vary (like how with $Df$ we can let $p$ vary)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen well… it’s not really true that *“the second tangent bundle only sees the total space of $TM$, meaning it forgets the bundle structure of $TM$ entirely”* because for every vector bundle $(E,\pi,M)$, the total space $TE$ has two structures of vector bundle; the first is the usual way $(TE,\pi_E,E)$ and the second (which arises since $E$ itself is a vector bundle) is $(TE,T\pi,TM)$. So, when $E=TM$, it follows that $TTM$ has two structures of vector bundle over $TM$. But yea, it does get confusing.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair and was a sloppy explanation on my part. I've removed the offending comments. Thanks for the correction. @peek-a-boo